# Highcharts month view

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with highstocks graphics. Year view looks fine, but when I switch to the month or week view, it does not divide by days and only puts one point, instead of building the chart with every day of the month / week. (Images below)

Year view:
[image: 1]

Week view:
[image: 2]

Comment: Hi Nuno Rolo, Could you reproduce this problem in some online code editor (example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6Lab32st/)?